# tabulator how to import as es module?

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to use tabulator in svelte. But it seems tabulator does not expose package type as module in package.json file. Because of that, we cannot import tabulator_esm as module.
When I try to import that as module, I get error from `vite` like `Unexpected token export`. Though there is other way to import like `await import('tabulator-tables');`.

Should not this option (`"type": "module") be in package.json?

Comment: `https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-silence-5emqr?file=/index.js`

Answer (score 2):

You can import Tabulator using the standard esm import sytanx, because the Tabulator library exports its core functionality seperate from its modules, you need to make sure you import the bits of the library you need:

To get the basic Tabulator core functionality:

```js
import {Tabulator} from 'tabulator-tables';
```

To get the basic Tabulator core functionality with specific modules:

```js
import {Tabulator, FormatModule, EditModule} from 'tabulator-tables';

Tabulator.registerModule([FormatModule, EditModule]);
```

To get full tabulator with all modules installed (this will be a much bigger source file):

```js
import {TabulatorFull as Tabulator} from 'tabulator-tables';
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tabulator-tables". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: have you done an `npm install tabulator-tables` first in the command line?

Comment: @OliFolkerd Can we import Tabulator if CDN is used ?

Comment: Yes, checkout the install docs https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/install#sources-cdn